# Change only part of image SRC attribute, but maintain file numbers

Tags: jquery

I need some help with jQuery:

**HTML**

```
    <div id="container">
     <div class="flexslider woodslider"> 
      <ul id="woods" class="slides">
        <li><img src="products/drewno/dab/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/dab/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/1.jpg" /></li>
      </ul>
     </div>

      <div class="flexslider woodslider"> 
      <ul id="hands" class="slides">
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/teak/1.jpg" /></li>
      </ul>
     </div>

       <div class="flexslider woodslider"> 
      <ul id="decors" class="slides">
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/1.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/3.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/2.jpg" /></li>
        <li><img src="products/drewno/sosna/1.jpg" /></li>  
      </ul>
     </div> 
    </div>

    <!-- empty holder for dynamic image. -->
    <div id="rightside">
    <img src="" />
    </div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$(window).load(function(e) {

      // image selected in first ul tag  
      var currentWood = $('#woods li img');
      currentWood.click(function(){

        // Get name of current clicked image
        var src = $(this).attr('src');  // full path
        var tarr = src.split('/');      //split path
        var file = tarr[tarr.length-2]; //get part of path
        var nums = tarr[tarr.length-1];
        var data = file.split('.')[0];  

        // last ul tag 
        // iterate over all images, and change path ( directory name - currentWood )

        $('#decors li img').each(function(){

          // this is problematic.
          // Images have got proper path ( dir name) but all have the same 
          // extension (n.jpg)
          $(this).attr('src', 'products/drewno/'+data+'/'+nums);  
          $(this).each(function() {
          var woodColor = $(this).attr('src');
          $('#rightside img').attr('src', woodColor);
          ///alert ($(this).attr('src'));
          });
        });       
      });// End of getting wood color info  
    }); // End of document ready
```

All I want, is to click on image on first `#woods ul` tag, get path of this image (I need most directory name (dab, teak or sosna) and use this part of directory name on images in
`#decors ul img.`

It is mostly done, but images in `#decors ul`, all have the same file number. 
How can I change variable nums to current file number of clicked `#woods img`?